# How to correctly send mail in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

Whenever I send mail in Laravel, this error message is thrown:

**Address in mailbox given [] does not comply with RFC 2822, 3.6.2.**

Here is my code:

```
public function contact_email(Request $request)
{
    $data['name'] = $request->name;
    $data['email'] = $request->email;
    $data['mobile'] = $request->mobile;
    $data['message'] = $request->message;

    Mail::send('email-view', ['data' => $data], function ($message) {
    $message->to(env('MAIL_USERNAME'))->subject('Contact Us Email Notification!!');
    });
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

What is the reason for that error?

Answer (score 1):

Please send mail like this:

```
Mail::send('frontend.englishlistening.contact_reply', $data, function($message) use ($toEmail, $toName, $fromEmail, $fromName, $subject){ 

          $message->from($fromEmail, $fromName);
          $message->to($toEmail, $toName);
          $message->subject($subject);
        });
```

**Note**: Please set env variable in any config file and get this email from config file.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could check if env('MAIL_USERNAME') is returning a correct mail format. In addition, you can add the 'from' method. You could do this (before Mail::...):

```
dd(env('MAIL_USERNAME'))
```

If you get a false value or not a value like a string and an email address with the correct format, forget it!

Are you sure need you receive the $data like an object? If not, you don't need to pass the var this way: ['data' => $data], just $data

Note that I didn't include the env('MAIL_USERNAME') here.

```
 Mail::send('email-view', $data, function ($message) {
     $message->from('thesystem@mail.com', 'the name of your app');
     $message->to('correct@email.com', 'This is a correct format')->subject('Example');
 });
```

But, if you need to pass the email address from env('MAIL_USERNAME') and you have verified that env('MAIL_USERNAME') is returning an email address correctly, why don't you try to include it into de $data variable? like this:

```
 $data = $request->only('name', 'email', 'mobile', 'message') + ['to' => env('MAIL_USERNAME')];
```

Or maybe you can use the email from the array:

```
public function contact_email(Request $request)
{
    $data = $request->only('name', 'email', 'mobile', 'message');

    Mail::send('email-view', $data, function ($message) use ($data) {
        $message->from('thesystem@mail.com', 'the name of your app');
        $message->to($data['email'], $data['name'])->subject('This is a way');
    });
 }
```

A tip for you:
You don't need to get data from $request this way. You could do like this:

```
  $data = $request->only('name', 'email', 'mobile', 'message');
```

I hope I can help you!